# How read external iframe via PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I want to track my package sent via the local post service: http://tandt.posta.sk/en.

With the tracking information, for example, RF166699170SK, I can locate the package.

but when I want to read it via PHP for example  curl_setopt, via file_get_contents, or another method, I read only HTML code but in output missing text for example "Item posted at post office Dlhé Pole" which I can see on page.

because this page use iframe with some private method 
http://www.posta.sk/en/sps-embed#tnt?q=RF166699170SK

but when I try to read this page (iframe), output missing information about package for example "Item posted at post office Dlhé Pole".

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="embed">
  <head>
    <link href="/sps/style.css?1450227250" media="screen,print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/sps/print.css?1445466449" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Slovenská pošta</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <script type="text/javascript">CONFIG={"api":"http://api.posta.sk/private","tntShare":{"en":"http://tandt.posta.sk/en/items/{number}","sk":"http://tandt.posta.sk/zasielky/{number}"},"lang":"sk","home":"http://www.posta.sk","embed":true}</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="/sps/script.js?1457665771" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
      var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
      try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-9600731-1");
        pageTracker._setDomainName("posta.sk");
        pageTracker._initData();
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
      } catch(err) {}
//]]>
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to read about this parcel via PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: If you check the page network activity you can see that http://api.posta.sk/private/search?q=RF166699170SK&m=tnt has a JSON response of what you need. However since it's in the path `private` I'm guessing you'd need permission to use it on your own site.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect network connection of the [page you linked](http://www.posta.sk/en/sps-embed#tnt?q=RF166699170SK) you can see that there some data is loaded via JSON request. In your example data is requested from http://api.posta.sk/private/search?q=RF166699170SK&m=tnt

Maybe it would be the easiest way to get data direct from this [API](http://api.posta.sk) instead of trying to parse the result. The key is the same. You can convert the response in php like this:

```
<?php
    $packageKey = 'RF166699170SK';
    $data = json_decode('http://api.posta.sk/private/search?q='.$packageKey.'&m=tnt', TRUE);
?>
```

But I don't know if it's allowed by your postal service. **You should ask if it's prohibited to do that.**

Answer (score 0):

There is an open API available for package tracking. Here you will find more information and documentation: https://www.posta.sk/informacie/api-dokumentacia

Example query: http://api.posta.sk/tracking?l=en&p=1&q=RF166699170SK